# Не видит идентификатора начала main

Tags: java, spring

Запустил пример из книги [Spring в действии от издательства ДМК пресс](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/java/978-5-94074-568-6/)

- Скачал примеры к книге
- Открыл проект "рыцарь"(knight)
- Собираю (Увы не собираться, говорит что  нету main'a)

---

```
package com.springinaction.knights;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class KnightAopMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("knights-aop.xml");
    
    Knight knight = (Knight) context.getBean("knight");
    
    knight.embarkOnQuest();
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложи лог ошибки, а также сам пример вместо ссылки на книгу, которую надо купить(!)

Comment: @Темкатоже  спасибо :3 вы мне показали как найти ответ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Надо сначала нажать на молоточек (**BuildProject(F11)**)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после сборки нажать **RunProject(F6)**

Всё заработало :3